# delete related data from a single table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-3.0

hi I have table with id usertypeId, managerId, SupervisorId n representative id..

when perticuler user login..
suppose manager then it will display the data related to manager..
when we want to delete the data then login user will not be deleted but when suppose superviosr is deleted then its related data like 
reperesentative shoulb be delete..

here is my code:

```
if (Session["UserTypeId"].ToString() == "2")
{
   DataTable dt1 = new BALUserProfile().SelectForGridManager(
      new BOLUserProfile() { Id = int.Parse(Session["UserId"].ToString()), 
                      ManagerId = int.Parse(Session["UserId"].ToString()) });

   for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
       if (dt1.Rows[i]["Id"].ToString() == Session["UserId"].ToString() &&
                 lblGUserTypeId1.ToString() == "2")
       {
           lblMessageGrid.Visible = true;
           lblMessageGrid.Text = "Data Can Not Be Delete";
       }
       else
       {
           //ObjBOL.Id = int.Parse(dt1.Rows[i]["Id"].ToString());
           //ObjBOL1.Id = int.Parse(dt1.Rows[i]["Id"].ToString());
           ObjBAL.Delete(ObjBOL);
           ObjBAL1.Delete(ObjBOL1);

       }
   }
} //this was missing
```

ya i know that but thanks...